# PTIJ: Why does the mishnah call us landlubbers?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The mishnah in Nedarim 3:6 says:

> If someone makes a neder forbidding benefit from sailors, he can benefit from landlubbers.  If he makes a neder forbidding benefit from landlubbers, he's forbidden to benefit from sailors, because sailors are included in landlubbers.

I tried to convince the Cap'n that the Mishnah is only talking about second rate sailors, like those awful Lost Boys after they stole our ship.  It worked until he saw the next line:

> Not only the second-rate sailors who go from Akko to Yafo, but even the real seafarers who go far away.

Are we really landlubbers?

Please help!  The Cap'n's been even more grouchy than usual since he saw this mishnah and is threatening to throw people to the crocodile left and right.

Thank you!  Best regards and have a good holiday!

-- Mr. Smee

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2):

## A Non-Jewish Captain

You are really landlubbers as Rashi and the Ran argue"אפילו הם עכשיו בים שסופם לעלות ליבשה"

However, this isn't such an insult - leaving a boat for dry land is the way of battle, and following the example of Titus - " אִם גִּבּוֹר הוּא יַעֲלֶה לַיַּבָּשָׁה וְיַעֲשֶׂה עִמִּי מִלְחָמָה" - If He is really mighty, let Him go up on dry land and there wage war against me.

If your captain is not Jewish, then the power of Titus can be something to look up to (although, not his actual actions).

## A Jewish Captain

If your captain is Jewish, then "לְעוֹלָם יָדוּר אָדָם בְּאֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל" -A person should always reside in Eretz Yisrael - and since "כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל בְּחֶזְקַת כַּשְׁרוּ" - Every Jew is assumed to be "Kosher" we know that he will in the end live in Isreal.